# Unexpected values when used unsigned int with %u and %x

Tags: ios, c

Today I'm working on a sample iOS application in which there is a code like:

```
unsigned int uCount = 0;
int iJoke = -7;
uCount = uCount + iJoke;
```

But when I printed it like:

```
╔══════════════════╦══════════════════════╦════════════╗
║ Format Specifier ║   Print Statement    ║   Output   ║
╠══════════════════╬══════════════════════╬════════════╣
║ %d               ║ NSLog(@"%d",uCount); ║ -7         ║
║ %u               ║ NSLog(@"%u",uCount); ║ 4294967289 ║
║ %x               ║ NSLog(@"%x",uCount); ║ fffffff9   ║
╚══════════════════╩══════════════════════╩════════════╝
```

I expected the output of %u as 7.

Then I used like:

```
unsigned int i = 0;
int j = -7;
i = i + abs(j);
```

And output is like:

```
╔══════════════════╦══════════════════════╦════════╗
║ Format Specifier ║   Print Statement    ║ Output ║
╠══════════════════╬══════════════════════╬════════╣
║ %d               ║ NSLog(@"%d",uCount); ║      7 ║
║ %u               ║ NSLog(@"%u",uCount); ║      7 ║
║ %x               ║ NSLog(@"%x",uCount); ║      7 ║
╚══════════════════╩══════════════════════╩════════╝
```

Although my issue is fixed with `abs()`, I'm curious to know why the %u gave `4294967289` as result in my first case.

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apart from signed vs. unsigned promotion - why do you expect it to print 7 when you just added -7 to 0? If there can be a reasonable expectation, that's -7.

Comment: @H2CO3: That was a sample code, not the enetire code I had written. I'm curios about the `4294967289`.

Comment: That's because unsigned integer arithmetic is explicitly defined by the standard such that overflow and underflow wrap around. You're subtracting seven from zero, why in the world would you expect that to be equivalent to adding seven?

Answer (score 6):

This assignment will assign in pattern representing `-7` (in 2's complement) to the unsigned int. Which will be very large unsigned value.

For 32 bit int this will be `2^32 - 7 = 4294967289`

And standard says it like below

`"If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2^n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [ Note: In a two’s complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation). —end note ]`

Comment: What page number is that quote from? Or can you provide a link, thank you.

Comment: Sorry i do not have any link.You can get it in **N3485 - Open-std.org** heading 4.7.2.

Comment: I'm sure I'll be able to find it. Even I forget some of the conversion rules involving unsigned operands!

Answer (score 0):

ARM stores negative numbers in [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) therefore `-7` is represented as `0xfffffff9` when read as an unsigned number.

The main advantage of representing negative numbers like this is that the instructions for adding signed integers is the same as adding unsigned integers.

Comment: But that's not the question I think.

Comment: @DineshRaja He's explaining why an unsigned numbers is promoted to a large positive number. Different systems have novel ways in doing this -- it's machine dependant.

Answer (score 0):

`ijoke` is promoted to an unsigned integer. On most compilers the signed bit is warped around to give you a large positive number.

Conversion rules are more complicated when unsigned operands are involoved.

For example, suppose that int is 16 bits and long is 32 bits. Then -1L < 1U, because 1U, which is an int, is promoted to to a signed long.

As you seem to have a 32bit int:

4294967296 - 7 = 4294967289

In general, most of the implicit conversions are those that convert a 'narrower' operand into a 'wider' one without losing information.